# What is profile tag in pom.xml and how to add it?

Tags: svn, maven-2, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am new to maven . I am first time using this and when I am trying to execute the release:perform it shows :-

```
[INFO] [WARNING] The requested profile "Repository" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact xxx.xxx.xxxx.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.43 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepository.xx.xxx.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Failed to transfer file: http://nexusrepository.xx.xxx.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/xxxp/yy/ys/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.43/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.43.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

Any help , welcome.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seens that the error is a 401 Unauthorized. The profile problem is a warning not an error, the profile "Repository" is been set but it does not exists in the settings.xml on home or the pom.xml of the project does not have any profile configured.

Comment: You are right.Now this error is not coming.But , when I am trying to execute release:perform it show error like below :-Failed to execute goal. Please go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721155/maven-releaseperform-failure.